# ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value , line 21 ORA-06512: at line at 5

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
    create or replace FUNCTION NOTGIVEN RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    IAD VARCHAR2(20);
    IND VARCHAR2(20);
    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT Q_ID  FROM QUESTION  WHERE NOT Q_ID in (SELECT Q.Q_ID FROM QUESTION Q INNER JOIN ANSWER A ON Q.Q_ID = A.Q_ID); 

    BEGIN
     OPEN C1;
      LOOP
      FETCH C1 INTO IND;
      EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;

      IF C1%FOUND THEN --if found then
      SELECT Q_ID INTO IAD FROM QUESTION WHERE Q_ID = IND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(IAD);
      END IF;
     IF C1%NOTFOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no found');--if not found
      END IF;
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE C1;
      END NOTGIVEN;
```

i tried to make function which gives all that question whose answer is not there, it gives appropriate output but show this type of error  ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value , line 21 ORA-06512: at line at 5  i also tried exception but it not work.

Comment: Please explain "it gives appropriate output". What do you mean by that, given that the function doesn't even compile (for the obvious reason that it is missing a RETURN statement)? Where and how does it give "appropriate output"?

Comment: i got it. thanks  @mathguy

Answer (score 0):

You've written a function which is supposed to return a `VARCHAR2` value, but there are no return statements in the code, and thus the routine doesn't return a value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NOTGIVEN
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  IAD VARCHAR2(20);
  IND VARCHAR2(20);

  CURSOR C1 IS SELECT Q_ID
                 FROM QUESTION
                 WHERE NOT Q_ID IN (SELECT Q.Q_ID
                                      FROM QUESTION Q
                                      INNER JOIN ANSWER A
                                        ON Q.Q_ID = A.Q_ID); 
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;

  LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO IND;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;

    IF C1%FOUND THEN --if found then
      SELECT Q_ID
        INTO IAD
        FROM QUESTION
        WHERE Q_ID = IND;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(IAD);
    END IF;

    IF C1%NOTFOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no found');--if not found
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE C1;

  RETURN IAD;  -- added
END NOTGIVEN;
```

Here I've added a statement to return `IAD` just before the `END NOTGIVEN`.

Best of luck.